# what is the out put?

Tags: mysql, database

Hi this is my code but when I run it in mysql it will show an error because of datatype but my friend checked it with sql server and it doesn't show error and also insert the value: 32769 .which of them is correct?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (A INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT T1 VALUES (32768.5);
```

Comment: it works for me in mysql 1.2.12?what is your?

Comment: mine is 1.1.6 ,the answer will be difference for difference verions of mysql?

Comment: You're using MySQL v1.1.6? You're using 20 year old software and you don't feel that this is worth mentioning in the question? Or more likely you have gotten the version of the database confused with the version of the software you are using to query the database...

Comment: really??? ok I will try the new one

Comment: @user329820: To get the version number run the command SELECT @@VERSION.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is (rightly in my view) getting upset because you have supplied a FLOAT value to a column that is expecting an INTEGER.

MS-SQL is performing an implicit conversion behind the scenes, but personally I think this is bad baheaviour - and MySQL's response (the error) is correct...

Comment: I haven't tested this - but something else you might want to think about is the range of the Integer data type...

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is correct. MySQL converts the number to an integer when inserting it. There is no error.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (A INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT T1 VALUES (32768.5);
SELECT * FROM T1;
```

Result:

```
A
32769
```

Version information:

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
'5.1.41-community'
```